# How to define the most efficient locator for element in DOM using Playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, e2e-testing, playwright, contentful

I am adding Playwright tests for a site with multiple locales. Page content is mainly rendered via CMS content (I'm using Contentful).

Using `locators` with hardcoded text, such as `await page.getByLabel('Blog Article Foo').click();` seems *very* brittle, especially with multiple locales.

Should I just avoid using *any* text-based locators and just use `await page.getByRole('heading').click();`?

This doesn't seem the "Playwright" way of testing, as I'm not testing what a user *sees* / interacts with, however the only alternative I can see is writing *lots* of very flakey tests for each locale and constantly update them.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Best practice for creating locators is using ID or so called unique identificator. This id can be many things, if the name of element is unique, it have unque tag and stuff like this. Do not depend on text, this is most bad way to construct a locator. Use DOM elements and create as short as possible locator, using css/xpath/playwright selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automation mostly it's not about user sees. It's about user flow that can be completed from scratch by user that matches product logic, using user resources (browser, etc.) as is.

Rendered components are usually checked by visual (screenshot) tests, and their part should be the lowest part of all coverage ([Testing Pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html)), where e2e can be split by functional and visual.

In most of cases you care about element that is exist / rendered / visible / clickable / has some styles and properties, but not on it's text itself. Text is usually defined by content keys, so in most of cases there is no need to test it. It can be tested by units, that element has key, and that key has value, but it is not the purpose of e2e testing.

1. If you have access to source code and can change it, best practice is to assign unique locators to the element and use it in e2e.

For example

- `[data-testid=heading]` or `page.getByDataTestId('heading')`
- `[data-hook=heading]`
- `[data-aid=heading]`

If you can't assign attributes by yourself and see this attributes - it's better to use them, they are for sure used for automation and there is high possibility they wouldn't change.

2. Then you should rely on element `id`, but in this case you should consider, that id is unique (it should by best practices, but some resources ignore this pattern) and not auto-generated.
3. Rely on element attribute that represents it's type or use purpose, `input[type=search]`, `[role=heading]`
4. Rely on attribute classes that seemed to be unique or combination between attributes and classes `.headingContainer`, `div.headingContainer`
5. Rely on custom tags like `name`, `title`, etc. But be aware, that they can be changed on different localisations. (Sometimes they are not, sometimes they are)
6. Rely on unique tags (for example, youtube has many unique tags), like `ytb-video-container`, `ytb-video-player`, etc.
7. Rely on href or src part `img[src*=imgur]`, `[href*=imgur]`. It's not the best practice, but can be used if src part wouldn't be changed.
8. And only if you don't have any other options, you can use text in construction of your locators. Text is very sensitive area that can be easily changed by product logic and also it differs on site localizations.
   For example, if you currently have only English, but in future you expect that site would be translated to Portuguese and you should test it, you should avoid any locators based on texts.

In building locators try to make it as easier as possible, use one-level if it is possible, if it is not - rely on component containers and get child elements from them.

Example:

```js
const posts = await page.locator('#blogPostContainer').all();
for(const post of posts) {
  await post.getByRole('heading').click();
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I always assumed e2e was more about visual-testing, but now I can it's both the visual AND the functional, nice one!